# CSS Flexbox - Multiple rows /w flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css

*Please see the design brief attached*
I'm trying to figure out how to align the Green colored box so that it equally equates to 25% of the height when viewed via my @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) query in my CSS. Along with an issue with the yellow blocks not aligning to the same height as the green colored box.

I cannot seem to arrange the content blocks in height order as seen on the design brief -> mobile view (right-side).

//HTML//

```
<div class="container">
<div class="red">
    <!-- <label>A</label> -->
</div>

<div class="yellow_green_wrapper">
    <div class="yellow"> <!-- <label>B</label> -->
        <div class='one'></div>
        <div class='two'></div>
        <div class='three'></div>
        <div class='four'></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="green">
        <!-- <label>C</label> -->
    </div>
</div>


<div class="blue">
    <!-- <label>D</label> -->
</div>
```

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .yellow_green_wrapper {
        flex-direction: column-reverse; 
    }

    .yellow.four {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .yellow  > div.two, .yellow  > div.three, .yellow  > div.four {
        width: 33%;
    }
}

.yellow_green_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.red , .blue, .green, .yellow {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.red label, .blue label, .green label, .yellow label{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.red {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(122, 45, 45, 0.9),rgba(168, 77, 77, 0.9));
}

.blue {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 70, 177, 0.9),rgba(144, 172, 209, 0.9));
}

.green {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(161, 241, 181, 0.9),rgba(101, 163, 114, 0.9));

}

.yellow {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.yellow, .green {
    height: 100%;
}

.yellow  > div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(248, 171, 6, 0.9),rgba(230, 181, 117, 0.9));
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.yellow  > div.one {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML?

Comment: For questions like these it is helpful to have a working code example incase users need to do a bit of testing, otherwise they need to get it running themselves to solve the issue.

Comment: I am able to run it using the code provided above, yes I can change the HTML if neccessary, but it must be done using flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layouts look suitable for using CSS grid. That way things are simplified as you don't need to individually define widths etc.

This snippet removed the grouping of yellow and green and uses the CSS grid-template-areas property to set up the various layouts.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'A A' 'B C' 'D D';
  rgrid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  rgrid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.red label,
.blue label,
.green label,
.yellow label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.red {
  grid-area: A;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(122, 45, 45, 0.9), rgba(168, 77, 77, 0.9));
}

.yellow {
  grid-area: B;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas: 'W W W' 'X Y Z';
}

.yellow>* {
  background: yellow;
}

.one {
  grid-area: W;
}

.two {
  grid-area: X;
}

.three {
  grid-area: Y;
}

.four {
  grid-area: Z;
}

.blue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 70, 177, 0.9), rgba(144, 172, 209, 0.9));
  grid-area: C;
}

.green {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(161, 241, 181, 0.9), rgba(101, 163, 114, 0.9));
  grid-area: D;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: 'A' 'C' 'B' 'D';
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1.5fr 1fr;
  }
  .yellow {
    grid-template-areas: 'W W' 'X Y' 'Z Z';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">
    <!-- <label>A</label> -->
  </div>

  <div class="yellow">
    <!-- <label>B</label> -->
    <div class='one'></div>
    <div class='two'></div>
    <div class='three'></div>
    <div class='four'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
    <!-- <label>C</label> -->
  </div>


  <div class="blue">
    <!-- <label>D</label> -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the CSS grid layout, I unfortunately can't use grid here as it's flexbox specific they are requesting. If I am to attempt to fix using flexbox, would I be needing to address the global height?

Comment: That's a shame as it's a simple grid - sorry I didn't know that was a restriction. Will  ponder flexbox but it always seems more fiddly given it's really for one dimensional layouts.